# App always crashes when editing video

Tags: objective-c, ios, video-processing

I'm trying to create a new app for editing video on iPhone, and using AVFoundation framework. When using AVMutableComposition and AVMutableVideoComposition to generate a video, the app crashed because of memory, is there any better way to edit video? or how to optimize it?

following is the code, I think it's mainly because the **animatedTitleLayer** I created, I add about 5 photos, to perform core animation.

```
    // Set up Core Animation layers to contribute a title animation overlay if we have a title set.
    if (self.titleText) {
        animatedTitleLayer = [self buildAnimatedTitleLayerForSize:videoSize];

        if (! forPlayback) {
            // For export: build a Core Animation tree that contains both the animated title and the video.
            CALayer *parentLayer = [CALayer layer];
            CALayer *videoLayer = [CALayer layer];
            parentLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, videoSize.width, videoSize.height);
            videoLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, videoSize.width, videoSize.height);
            [parentLayer addSublayer:videoLayer];
            [parentLayer addSublayer:animatedTitleLayer];

            if (! videoComposition) {
                // No transition set -- make a "pass through video track" video composition so we can include the Core Animation tree as a post-processing stage.
                videoComposition = [AVMutableVideoComposition videoComposition];

                [self buildPassThroughVideoComposition:videoComposition forComposition:composition];
            }

            videoComposition.animationTool = [AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool videoCompositionCoreAnimationToolWithPostProcessingAsVideoLayer:videoLayer inLayer:parentLayer];
        }
    }

    if (videoComposition) {
        // Every videoComposition needs these properties to be set:
        videoComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30); // 30 fps
        videoComposition.renderSize = videoSize;
    }
```

Is there any other to convert core animation to video? in the above code, I have to add all photos at the same time.

There is an app, [Splice video editor](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/splice/id386894062), did very good, fast and stable. What I'm going to do is almost the same as it, convert core animation to video, but slow and unstable.

Comment: Do you have any code, line number, or step in the process where it crashes?

Comment: Converting coreanimation to video is difficult.  I'd recommend not using CoreAnimation to do this.

Comment: @alexy13, do you have any suggestion? which library should i use?